# How do you confirm network adapter is gigabit capable?

Tags: networking, network-speed

Upgrading my network to gigabit speeds and don't know how to determine if the NIC in one of the systems is capable of gigabit speed.

The documentation from the manufacturer states this:

```
Network adapter
10/100/1000 Ethernet LAN on system board
```

However when I go to the properties of the NIC under Speed & Duplex my only options are:

```
10 Mb Full
10 Mb Half
100 Mb Full
100 Mb Half
Auto
```

Is there a command line I can run that will give me more detail about the NIC?

Windows 7 x64 OS

---

**New Info:**
The new switch I just bought has a light to indicate 1000Mbps. I can tell from the light that this NIC is indeed negotiating at 1000Mbps but I'd still like to know how to determine this from the console in windows.

Comment: What's the model number on the device in device manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) requires Auto-negotiation. That's why there are no selections for 1000 Mb Full or Half.

Plug the NIC into a Gigabit switch port and see what the NIC reports as the speed (right click the NIC and select Status to see the speed). You should be able to verify it at the switch also by looking at the port indicator LEDs or switch port info on a managed switch.

You can also check it on the Networking tab of Task Manager.

Comment: Cool, reported 1.0 Gbps in both places. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `wmic` query to get more information about NIC:

```
wmic NIC
```

If you want to get speed of all enabled NIC, try:

```
wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed
```

Comment: Nice, this will be perfect for scripting.